# Allow users to select online or offline mode for ClickOnce install

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation, clickonce

When publishing a ClickOnce application through Visual Studio, I can select either online only mode or offline. Currently we are using offline mode, but some of our users want to use it in a purely online mode. Of course, I could publish it twice to two different locations—one for each installation mode—but this seems like a hack. Is it possible to allow the end user to select the install mode they prefer?